# latex : Exclude draftwatermark from specific pages

Tags: watermark, draftwatermark

I am using draftwatermark package. Is there any option to exclude watermark from some specific pages? Say no watermark from pg 3-4. I can not use xwatermark package. It conflicts with the geometry package of my document. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{draftwatermark} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\SetWatermarkAngle{45} 
\SetWatermarkLightness{.8} 
\SetWatermarkFontSize{10cm} 
\SetWatermarkScale{5} 
\SetWatermarkText{\tt{12345}}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-20] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a command `\watermarkoff` that works like the one for the `background` package, and place it in the page you want to turn off.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\SetWatermarkAngle{45} 
\SetWatermarkLightness{.8} 
\SetWatermarkFontSize{10cm} 
\SetWatermarkScale{5} 
\SetWatermarkText{\tt{12345}}

\makeatletter
\def\watermarkoff{%
        \@sc@wm@stampfalse
}
\makeatother


\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-8]
\watermarkoff
\lipsum[9-12] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmmm, does not seem to be working if I use the watermark for included pdfs... thanks anyway.

Comment: With TexLive 2020 I get this error message: `! Undefined control sequence.\watermarkoff ->\@sc@wm@stampfalse \watermarkoff`

Answer (score 4):

As the current documentation for draftwatermark at [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark) says in section 2.1, one can use `\DraftwatermarkOptions{stamp=false}` anywhere in the document, which will turn off the watermark from there on.

Using `\DraftwatermarkOptions{stamp=true}` one can turn the watermarks on again.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This works and is easier than defining the new command. Based on the dates of the answers, I suspect this wasn't in the package functionality when the question was first asked.

Answer (score 1):

With package `background` you can select which pages don't show a default watermark. You must use command `\NoBgThispage` in every individual page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{background}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-8]
\NoBgThispage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ignasi. I tried background package in my file. But it is showing error whenever I am inserting new page. Error is ! Undefined control sequence.
\sc@everypage@hook...@watermark\oldbg@material                             
l.44 \newpage

Comment: Yeah, this example also did **not** work when using the `draftwatermark` package. This completely by-passes the `draftwatermark` package and just slaps its own "*draft*" watermark. It has no affect on the `draftwatermark` package and its configurations.

Comment: @CodeDoggo I don't understand the comment (and down vote?) My answer doesn't mention `draftwatermark` package at all. It only proposes an alternative solution to avoid watermarks in specific pages.