# Package draftwatermark: no watermark on the first page

Tags: draftwatermark

I need to add a watermark on all pages of a latex document but the first.

Currently, I'm using [the draftwatermark package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark), but I haven't suceeded yet.

Any advice or suggestion?

I tried the xwatermark package, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191477/hiding-watermark-for-first-page), but it came out that it is not compatible with other packages I'm using.

Comment: You can modify [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288884/4778), it will work in your case. Can you manage to make it work? Let me know here.

Comment: I received a notification from a comment of yours. It worked then?

Comment: @Aleanno: Yes, thanks! I tried to write down the solution I adopted as a comment, but it was too long. So, I added an answer.

Comment: I see that, but if the linked question helped you, then your answer is the same as the other one and this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, it can be deleted if you think it is not useful for other users, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Alenanno: I tried the solution he suggested and it worked like a charm! 
I slightly modified [his code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288881/latex-exclude-draftwatermark-from-specific-pages/288884#288884), adding a `\watermarkon` macro and now watermarks can be easily enabled/disabled for every single page.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

%%%% for the 1 page %%%%
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{blindtext}  
\SetWatermarkAngle{45} 
\SetWatermarkLightness{.8} 
\SetWatermarkFontSize{10cm} 
\SetWatermarkScale{8} 
\SetWatermarkText{\tt{DRAFT}}

%%% Macro to disable watermark
\makeatletter
\def\watermarkoff{%
        \@sc@wm@stampfalse
}
\makeatother

%%% Macro to enable watermark
\makeatletter
\def\watermarkon{%
        \@sc@wm@stamptrue
}
\makeatother


\begin{document} 

%%% no watermark on the first page
\watermarkoff
%%%% for the 1 page %%%%
\includepdf[pages={1},offset=0 0, delta=0 0, scale=1]{./lshort}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%% watermark on the second one
\watermarkon
\Blindtext
\newpage

%%% no watermark on the third page
\watermarkoff
\Blindtext
\newpage

%%% watermark on the remaining pages
\watermarkon
\Blindtext
\newpage
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The first page (lshort) is the cover page of [The (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).